# Wi-Fi Router Charger: is 100-240V input an acceptable replacement for a 220-240V charger?

Tags: voltage, charger

My wi-fi router charger is broken and I'm looking to buy a replacement.

The old one says - input 220-240V 50/60Hz 0.5A, output 12V 2.5A, efficiency level V

Online, the closest I found has input 100-240V 50/60Hz 0.8A, output 12V,2.5A,30.0W,ef lvl VI

Would this still work fine?